# Combine columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there a way to combine 2 columns?

For example, I have a survey asking a Yes/No question.
But the survey puts all yes’ in one column, and no’s in another.
So it will look like

```
column 1    column 2
yes 
yes 
             no
yes 
             no
             no
yes
```

And I want it to look like

```
column 1
yes 
yes 
no
yes 
no
no
yes
```

Merging will delete one of the columns...and that's about all I know.
Hopefully it won't involve VBA since I don't know any of that.

Comment: Can't you just have a third column and concaternate columns 1+2 into it?

Comment: @SamWard looks like that will work...can't you just put that as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, repeat of previous answer.  Concatenate the columns in a third column using the "&" operator. For example, if the "yes" column starts in cell A2 and the "no" column starts in cell B2, enter the formula =A2&B2 in cell C2 and then copy the formula down in column C to the end of your data.  If you want the new column to be values then copy it and then special paste it in place as values.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to entering a formula in a third column, you can also

- Select column 1
- Goto (Ctrl-G) -> Special (Alt+S) -> Blank Cells (Alt+K, Enter)
- Delete cells (Ctrl--), Shift left (Alt-L)

This way, all blank cells in column a will be selected